# Micronaut Configuration Injection does not work as expected

Tags: micronaut

Micronaut version I am using : 2.3.3

I tried out the examples mentioned in "4.3 Configuration Injection" of Micronaut documentation(URL given below). Especially, the annotations @Property & @Value. However, my debug break-points does not pause in any of these methods, during Micronaut start. Has anyone faced the same issue & able to find any solution for this?

https://docs.micronaut.io/2.3.3/guide/index.html

Here is the entries in "application.yml" file

```
micronaut:
    my:
      engine:
        manufacturer: BGH
        cylinders: 6
```

Here is the code. I am expecting my debug break-point for the method "setManufacturer" & "getCylinders" to hit. But that does not happen:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class EngineConfig {

  @Property(name = "my.engine.cylinders")
  protected int cylinders;

  private String manufacturer;

  public int getCylinders() {
    return cylinders;
  }

  public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
  }

  @Inject
  public void setManufacturer(@Property(name = "my.engine.manufacturer") String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
  }

}
```

Here is another code I tried, but "getCylinders" method is not getting hit during debug.

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Value;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class EngineImpl {

  @Value("${my.engine.cylinders:6}")
  protected int cylinders;

  public int getCylinders() {
    return cylinders;
  }

  public String start() {
    return "Starting V" + getCylinders() + " Engine";
  }

}
```

Comment: I have added enough details now & its fit for this question to be re-opened.

Comment: The code is referencing a config setting named `my.engine.cylinders` but your `application.yml` is assigning a value to `micronaut.my.engine.cylinders`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem in your case is that you forgot the "@Singleton" annotation above your bean class.
If you forget this annotation, its instance won't be created in the Micronaut IOC container. And hence, you are not getting debug point(as it is not really getting initialized in your case.)

Else can you please post your code if this is not the problem in your case, as the example works correctly for me.

Comment: AmitB10, Thanks for your response. I have added code to this question. I do have "@Singleton" annotation.

Comment: I don't think `@Singleton` is the issue.  The config property referenced in the source code `my.engine.cylinders` is out of sync with the config property defined in `application.yml`, `micronaut.my.engine.cylinders`.

Comment: Yes, first the code and application.yml file were not posted. But now looking at those files, it should be @Value("${micronaut.my.engine.cylinders}") instead of @Value("${my.engine.cylinders}")